# How does Whatsapp track time in Android?

Tags: android, time, whatsapp

I was looking for a way to get the Whatsapp messages in real-time in Android (not daily at 04:00 AM).
I couldn't find anything useful.
I thought it may be possible to manipulate the time at which Whatsapp does its backup and this way I could force it to backup whenever I want.

**Question:**

Does Whatsapp use the system time for its regular backups or does it check the time using a server?

Comment: its already possible in watsapp to create backup whenever u wants.

Comment: unfortunately not programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp uses system time for regular backups. But however you can also create backup whenever you want. You might test how whatsapp uses system time like this. You can register your whatsapp with some other country number(say 1st country) and start using your whatsapp in other country(say 2nd country). You get messages and last seen with the time of 2nd country if you have adjusted your system time to that of 2nd country.

Comment: Thanks. although i meant to backup the messages programmatically :)